# Is the comment property honoured by GORM for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, grails, grails-orm

Comments should be stored as extended properties in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'Your Comment goes here',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'Your schema name',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Your table name',
    @level2type = NULL,
    @level2name = NULL
```

If you're managing your DB using SSDT you can put this information in the Description property of the table and it will execute the SPROC above automatically.

Sorry - I just re-read the title and noticed GORM. I'm not familiar with this but it is standard SQL Server behaviour to store description / comments in the extended properties as I stated above, so it should work for GORM.

Comment: Thanks Greg.  Yes, the issue is specifically related to Grails and GORM.